# Android UncaughtExceptionHandler not called if I use ACRA

Tags: android, acra

It works on Android 5.0, but it won't work on Jellybean devices.

```
@ReportsCrashes(
    formKey = "", // This is required for backward compatibility but not used
    formUri = "dummyurl",
    reportType = org.acra.sender.HttpSender.Type.JSON,
    httpMethod = org.acra.sender.HttpSender.Method.PUT,
    formUriBasicAuthLogin="adminTest",
    formUriBasicAuthPassword="adminTest",
    mode = ReportingInteractionMode.TOAST,
    resToastText = R.string.crash_toast_text)
public class Application extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        init();
        ACRA.init(this);
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(sUncaughtExceptionHandler);
    }

    private UncaughtExceptionHandler sUncaughtExceptionHandler = new UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
            Log.i(LogTag, "uncaughtException: ");

            dummyMethod();

            Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler().uncaughtException(
                thread, ex);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: I don't know why it's working in L but the thing that is wrong here that you are setting two UncaughtExceptionHandler one you assigned manually and one ACRA is creating for you and that is not right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ACRA sets its own UncaughtExceptioHandler that performs the error reporting and then delegates to any UncaughtExceptionHandler that existed before it.

So if you want your UncaughtExceptionHandler to be called once ACRA has completed the error reporting, then you need to set your exception handler **before** calling `ACRA.init(this);`

Since you are sending Toast notifications you also need to set `forceCloseDialogAfterToast` as the assumption is that the defaultExceptionHandler is the one from Android framework that will display a force close dialog and you wouldn't want to show that if also showing a Toast.

Comment: I have tried this,  
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(sUncaughtExceptionHandler);  
ACRA.init(this);      but still not working,

Comment: Set `forceCloseDialogAfterToast` to true as well.

Comment: I have tried the Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandle before calling ACRA.init(this);  This is worked for me. Thanks for helped

Comment: Take care: delegation to the previous handler happens only 1. if `ACRA.getConfig().mode() == ReportingInteractionMode.SILENT
                || (ACRA.getConfig().mode() == ReportingInteractionMode.TOAST && ACRA.getConfig()
                        .forceCloseDialogAfterToast())` is true, or 2. if ACRA is not enabled or 3. if ACRA throws an exception itself (check `ErrorReporter.java`)